# How to get dates by days which have intervals of 7 days each

Tags: flutter

hello guyz am new to flutter and am practicing on dates then i encounter a difficulty on how can i acheive the result same below using a loop or something in order to get this result.

so far i tried is

```
final now = DateTime.now();

for(var d = 1 ; d <= 5 ; d++){
  // Don't know whats next to do here to get the same result below
}
```

i want result like this

```
Apr 19, 2022
Apr 26, 2022
May  3, 2022
May 10, 2022
May 17, 2022
```

can some help me and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart's `DateTime` class has an `add` function, where you can specify a duration which will be added the current Date.

Therefore, what you can do is:

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();

for(var d = 1; d <= 5; d++) {
  ...
  now = now.add(Duration(days: 7)); // here you can specify your interval. Also possible: hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds and microseconds
}
```

I'll recommend reading the Docs, e.g. [DateTime Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) and [Duration Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html)

Comment: I'm not sure *WHAT* the OP is asking for.  [DateTime.add()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) is certainly a good guess.  I would also encourage the OP to familiarize themselves with the Dart API documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/index.html